# Can't find System.Data.SQLite in MonoMac project

Tags: mono, monomac

I'm trying to use a SQLite database in a MonoMac program (with the intent of reusing the database in a MonoTouch app).

I've tried two different ORMs, and both fail with the same issue.  Searching around online, I discovered the `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug` flag, and a lot of information, but I can't quite get it working.

Currently, I'm referencing Mono.Data.SQLite, but from what I've found, it seems that that is just a wrapper for a system-specific version.

Here's the error output:

> Mono: The request to load the assembly System.Data v2.0.0.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
>   Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0_*b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll'.
>   Mono: Image addref System.Data[0x62ada0] -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0*_b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll[0xbd5600]: 2
>   Mono: Assembly System.Data[0x62ada0] added to domain SQLTest.exe, ref_count=1
>   Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0_*b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll.dylib: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0*_b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll.dylib, 9): image not found
>
> Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0_*b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll'.
>   Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/4.0.0.0*_b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll.config'.
>   Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Data/System.Data.config'.
>   Mono: Assembly Ref addref Catnap[0x6213c0] -> System.Data[0x62ada0]: 2
>   Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Data[0x62ada0] -> mscorlib[0x1001d90]: 6
>   Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/System.Data.SQLite.dll'.
>   Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/System.Data.SQLite.exe'.
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'System.Data.SQLite'
>     at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string)
>     at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Catnap.Database.BaseDbAdapter.ResolveConnectionType (System.String connectionTypeAssemblyName) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Catnap.Database.Sqlite.BaseSqliteAdapter..ctor (System.String connectionTypeAssemblyName) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Catnap.Database.Sqlite.SqliteAdapter..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Catnap.DbAdapter.get_Sqlite () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at YAData.Connection.Connect () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at SQLTest.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

I've tried adding a config file with

```
<configuration>
   <dllmap dll="sqlite3" target="/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib" os="!windows"/>
</configuration>
```

to the application, and I've tried modifying `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/etc/mono/config`, but nothing has worked.  It's still looking in the wrong places and not finding SQLite.

Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know **why** it was looking for System.Data.SQLite, but I recompiled one of the ORMs myself rather than using the provided dll, and it worked.  I'm sure some of the problem was that I was using the MonoTouch dll in a MonoMac project.  Recompiling CoolStorage (which uses `Mono.Data.Sqlite` instead of `System.Data.SQLite`) resolved it.

If anyone can give me an explanation, I'll switch accepted answers.

On with the code!